# Пагинация постов в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, циклы, pagination

Всем привет, подскажите как правильно реализовать пагинацию в WP:

Есть 9 постов, у каждого соответственно своя страница.

Есть страница которая показывает в карточках эти посты(а точнее только картинку оттуда и название), но карточек всего 6.

Нужна пагинация, с помощью которых можно будет увидеть остальные 3 на другой странице(в данном случае)

Comment: В настройках чтения поставь не 10, а 3

Comment: @SeVlad пробовал - не получилось, наверное изза того что не выбрал какая страница будет страницей для записи, изза того, что  у меня страницы записей будет 2, а там можно выбирать 1, поэтому хочу какой нибудь функцией или циклом воспользоваться,чтобы их в каждой из двух страниц были карточки своих записей

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Comment: Фууууух, потратил два дня чтобы решить проблему, спасибо огромное добрый человек!